# Where to put file of default values in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have a file with ~ 100 default values that I need to load into a Windows Phone 8 app at startup. Now where in the Visual studio project do I put this file?

I guess it should be in IsolatedStorage, but I've only found examples of how you create new files programmatically here and then read from them. My question is how do you put an existing file in IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my head, default values are like "factory reset" values, and so they should always be read-only. Which means that I would put that file into either an embedded resource or I would mark it as Content to be deployed with the binaries, and I would not try to put it into IsolatedStorage.

However, if you meant that this is a sort of user-settings file with initial values, or a program-data file with initial values, then I would probably still start with putting it in as an embedded resource or content, but would copy it from there to the IsolatedStorage are.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track. It worked when I marked the file as Content.